# WebClient.DownloadDataAsync is returning corrupted data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I am trying to prototype a data upload and download from an application to a web API. The prototype uploads a file (test.zip) to the server. The server saves it as a new file to the same folder and then returns test.zip again and the client saves the received file. Upload is working perfectly, and download runs without errors. However, when writing the received data to a file the file size is inflated by about 30% and corrupt when I try to open it.

I have tried to find people with similar problems online but haven't found any results. I am new to this topic so am unsure what to try myself.

Client (Console App):

```cs
static void Main()
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
    Upload();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Upload()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var file = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Users/LPQ/Downloads/Working Folder/test.zip");
    webClient.UploadDataCompleted += (s, e) => Download(webClient);
    webClient.UploadDataAsync(new Uri("localhost/API/APISync/Upload"), file);
}

static void Download(WebClient webClient)
{
    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes("C:/Users/LPQ/Downloads/Working Folder/test_SentToClient.zip", e.Result);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    };
    webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("localhost/API/APISync/Download"));
}
```

Server

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("API/APISync/Upload")]
public async Task Upload()
{
    var fileContents = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:/Users/LPQ/Downloads/Working Folder/test_SentToServer.zip", fileContents);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("API/APISync/Download")]
public byte[] Download()
{
    return File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Users/LPQ/Downloads/Working Folder/test.zip");
}
```

text.zip is 30,837 KB.

The upload results in a file created called test_SentToServer.zip of 30,837 KB.

The download results in a file created called test_SentToClient.zip, however it is 41,116 KB and cannot be opened (corrupt).

Obviously i would expect the file received by the client to be 30,837 KB again.

[image: Result screenshot]

Comment: side note: if you look at [remarks section of docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) you will see that `WebClient` is not recomended for use by Microsoft

Comment: Thanks @vasily.sib I'll try out HttpClient instead.

To note:
I have double checked the byte array size of the file before and after the download.
Before return (on server): 31576982
After download (on client): 42102646
So it is definitely occurring during the download process.

Comment: Look at you response (from `API/APISync/Download`). I bet there is a HTTP header `Content-Type: application/json;`, am I right?

Comment: @vasily.sib the Headers property in the sender object is empty. The EventArgs object with the Result property is just a byte[]. Is there another way i can check?

Comment: @vasily.sib Okay now for the weird. I just tried using HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync() method to my API and the result is exactly the same as WebClient with the received file being 41,116KB! This suggests to me also that the API is the cause. Perhaps headers like you suggested. How can i check better than the properties of the received objects? Changing it to GetAsync and checking the response -> Content -> Headers properties it does contain application/json

Comment: @LPQ Check it in browser. HttpClient does the same as browser does. But in browser you can check faster whether your api works properly. Also you can see headers etc.

Comment: @mtkachenko In browser I just see a base64 string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this solved after an afternoon of pulling out hair and it was something so simple.

In the WebClient.DownloadComplete event handler it was changed to this to get the correct file data from the response:

```cs
var base64String = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Result).Replace("\"", "");
var fileData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
File.WriteAllBytes("C:/Users/LPQ/Downloads/Working Folder/test_SentToClient.zip", fileData);
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

The response from the server was a byte array of my data in base64 format and not the byte array of my data. So it required to be converted to base64 string and then to a decoded byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't return raw bytes, use [FilePathResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.filepathresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) instead

```
return new FilePathResult(path, "application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: thanks, but that resulted in a client received file on only 1KB. Additionally (I should have probably included this in the original post) I am using files purely as a way of getting large data sizes. The requirements are to save and receive raw bytes.

Comment: @LPQ does it work from browser? Did you fix content-type? What's status code of http request?

Comment: I set the content-type to "application/zip" and "application\octet-stream" with the same result of 1kb.
The download needs to go from API to an application.

Comment: But it should work from browser too. It's just easier to test.